# ROS2 Gazebo garden bridge

Tags: ros2, rosdep

I am trying to set up the bridge between the ROS2 and gazebo garden (Ubuntu 20.04).

I have an issue with installation of ros_gz dependencies ([link](https://github.com/gazebosim/ros_gz/tree/ros2))

```
rosdep install -r --from-paths src -i -y --rosdistro humble
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
ros_gz_bridge: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [gz-transport12]
ros_gz_sim_demos: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [gz-sim7]
ros_gz_image: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [gz-transport12]
ros_gz_sim: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [gz-transport12]
Continuing to install resolvable dependencies...
#All required rosdeps installed successfully
```

ROS2 humble was installed according to this [link](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Installation/Alternatives/Ubuntu-Development-Setup.html)

Gazebo garden was installed according to this [link](https://gazebosim.org/docs/garden/install_ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

try following the instructions using humble branch. For reference:
https://github.com/gazebosim/ros_gz/tree/humble

Also refer to the table in the readme, which suggests the different combinations of ros2 and gazebo versions.